# LinAlgError: SVD did not converge in matplotlib PCA

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, ipython

I am trying to do a PCA on a matrix in matplotlib but keep encountering LinAlgError: SVD did not converge. I've checked my data for bad values. I was able to implement a PCA on a similar dataset with no problems, but in this case I switched the dimensions since the number of rows must be greater than the number of columns for the PCA class. My matrix has 345 rows and 146 columns of floats between 0.0 and 1.0. I'm not sure what's going on here or how to debug. I'm working in iPython if that makes a difference, have both the latest versions of numpy and scipy (I've read in previous versions there were bugs associated with this function).

I also encounter this warning on the same cell, I'm not sure if it's related:

`RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide`

`return (x - self.mu)/self.sigma`

Here is my code for the cell:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.mlab import PCA
t = []
c = []
master = []
for s in sample_master_list.values():
   if s.t2d:
      t.append(s.pathways.values())
   else:
      c.append(s.pathways.values())
master = t + c
pca = PCA(np.array(master))
```

If anyone has any tips about how I can figure out what the problem is causing the problem I would really appreciate it.

Comment: It would be good to attach a stand alone code, with variables `sample_master_list` and `s` to allow us to run and reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that one of the columns in `master` is constant.  Take a look at `np.std(master)`.  If one of the values is 0, the corresponding column of `master` is a constant.  If that's the case, you could use `pca = PCA(np.array(master), standardize=False)` as a possible work-around.  The `standardize` argument tells PCA whether or not to divide the data in each column by the standard deviation of that column.  (Or you could drop the constant column.  It isn't providing any useful information anyway, so there would be no harm in ignoring it.)